# what is the best approach in connecting to server periodically and check for update availability

Tags: android

looking for links/resources and approach on connecting to server through web service API periodically in background and check for availability of updated data on the server instead of parsing server response every time.

I have a server which has some data and will be updated in a month time. I exposed a service on top of it and it is used by android app. So, to reduce server load & improve battery, I would like to call the service periodically to check latest data is available or not.

I really appreciate if anyone can help me out on this.

Comment: Use `AlarmManager` with an `IntentService`.

Comment: Use GCM. Send a msg from server to device that will say to device, hay you have an update. So device can contact to server for update.

Comment: service is the best approch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best chance would be to use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) messages from the server, in such case a logic that could be used is the following:

1. Android devices registers with the GCM service and requests initial data
2. Server logs the last time a specific Android device has updated each data
3. On each data update, the server sends a message to the devices registered
4. Devices request new data
5. Server uses the last update log to send only new data and updates  the update log

Another nice option, would be to use the Android [Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) with longer refresh intervals.

1. On each response from the server, send the date of the last update
2. Devices will send this data along with the request for updated data i.e. `/request/data?last_update=[epoch_here]`
3. Server searches for data that are more recent than the date specified and if it doesn't find any it responds with a `304 Not Modified`

You could combine the above options, for faster updates using GCM and very long intervals for cases where the device does receive the GVM message, i.e. if the device is not used for a certain period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Polling periodically can cause phone to drain battery fast. Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) allows server to push notification on devices. So when the update is ready, you just tell the phone and it connect to server to grab the update.

Quoted from Android Developer Page about GCM:

> This could be a lightweight message telling your app there is new data
>   to be fetched from the server (for instance, a movie uploaded by a
>   friend), or it could be a message containing up to 4kb of payload data
>   (so apps like instant messaging can consume the message directly).

Comment: Much more complex than using `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService` if the data on the server is going to only update once each month.